# How to paste python-code chunk to HTML page

Tags: python, html

Let say I have below python code placed in one of my `IDE`

```
import math  
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
.....
some other python code
```

Now, I have a web-page with `HTML`, `CSS` etc, and I want to place above code-chunk in that web-page. Manually, I was just copy-paste above code and then manually apply appropriate styling using `CSS`. For big code-chunk, it is really cumbersome. Moreover, with that approach, few important stuffs like indentation would get garbled, so when site-viewer would copy-paste that code-chunk from my web-page in his python-workplace, it might not work properly.

I am looking for suggestion if there is any easier way to achieve the same, i.e. I can just take the code-chunk from my `IDE` and place within appropriate div of page's `source code`.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ask yourself: *why* are you doing this? And why it's just html? Nowadays webpages have some logic where the code could be inserted, but if you're doing static pages, consider making template/templates and filling it/them using some tool (e.g. use Jinja and fill it using simple Python code), instead of filling them manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can paste your code in the `<pre><code>` tags , you can always play out with the CSS

```
<pre>
<code style="display:block; white-space:pre-wrap;background: hsl(220, 80%, 90%); ">

 <!--- paste your code from IDE here ---->
</code>
</pre>
```